# Is the non-parametric Bootstrap efficient or not?

Tags: bootstrap, nonparametric

If my original sample is strictly following a specific distribution (eg Gamma), is there any chance then that my non-parametric bootstrap will not be accurate for great sample sizes? If yes, is this anywhere indicated in literature?